# Force on a wire due to an electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I want to measure the magnetic field $B$ of an electromagnet at various points in space to develop an equation that describes the magnetic field of an electromagnet at any distance knowing the turns $N$ and the intensity of the current passing through the electromagnet $I$.

I have thought to build the electromagnet powered with a regular battery and a nail wrapped around the wire to increase the magnetic field. To measure the magnetic field I thought to put a wire next to it with another current $i$ to measure with a dynamometer the force $F$ that I need to apply to it to make the wire stay in position and then know the magnetic field $B$ with Lorentz's Law.

I have attempted briefly due to lack of time, but no effect was seen on the wire. Is this a good experiment and if so, why?

Comment: Probably the force is too small to detect with your dynamometer. You need an apparatus or instrument which is more sensitive to small forces.

Comment: See [Rough, easy DIY method of measuring magnetic field strength](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46292) of which this question might be a duplicate.

Comment: The batter used may not provide sufficient voltage to produce a measurable force in the wire.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by wrapping the wire around the nail (many times).  For best results use a nail which is attracted by a magnet.  The field outside of an electromagnet leaves the magnet from one end (the North seeking pole), spreads out, loops around, and reenters at the other end.  The field varies in both magnitude and direction from point to point.  Assuming you could measure the force on a short piece of current carrying wire, the result would reflect the average field over the length of the wire (and its connections).  For point to point measurements you need (an expensive) Hall Effect field strength meter. The shape of the field can be explored with a small magnetic compass or by sprinkling iron filings on a piece of cardboard in the plane of the nail.  The field at points around a well formed solenoid can be calculated (on a computer) by doing a numeric integration of the contributions from short segments of the current carrying wire. At distant points, the field can be estimated using a “dipole approximation” based on the “pole strength”.  A well fitted ferromagnetic core (your nail) increases the field strength by a factor which depends on its size, shape and material.  One possibility for measuring the horizontal component of a magnet field would be to measure the period of oscillation of a small compass needle. It should be proportional to one over the square root of the field strength. You could calibrate against a known value for the earths field in your area. The needle could be set in motion by passing a magnet nearby. You may need to video the motion and play back frame by frame.  Again, this would give an average value of the field over the length of the needle.